# Did or Do with (past) verb in question

Tags: questions, time

Right form of the question about past:

Example:

1. Do you thought about...
2. Did you think about...
3. Did you thought about...

Or which to use and when?

Comment: Only the second one is correct. When you put *did*, it automatically talks about the past tense and hence, the verb following it does not take its present tense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2) **Did** you think about...

is simple past tense and is fine as is. Similar:

> I **did** not think about...

Regarding 1. and 3., they are using *thought* as [Present Perfect tense](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html), as an action that may have occurred at some indeterminate time up to the present.
As such, you need to use a form of *have* as an auxiliary verb.

> I **have** thought about everything. (up to the present time)
>   I **had** thought about everything. (some period of time in the past)

In your examples:

> 1) **Have** you thought about...
>   3) **Had** you thought about...